How to capture screen when qr code detected in zxin.net.maui?
I'm trying to take a picture of the QR code using the zxing.net.maui library but the image is always black
 this my xaml
 `  <zxing:CameraBarcodeReaderView x:Name="zxing"      BarcodesDetected="zxing_BarcodesDetected" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />`
 cs code
`private async  void zxing_BarcodesDetected(object sender, BarcodeDetectionEventArgs e)
 {
  
  var first = e.Results?.FirstOrDefault();
  if (first is not null)
      {
      Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
      {
          await CaptureScreenshotAsync();
      }
 })};`

` private async Task CaptureScreenshotAsync()
 {
    try
       {
       
        var screenshot = await zxing.CaptureAsync();
        if (screenshot != null)
        {
            var stream = await screenshot.OpenReadAsync();
#if ANDROID
            
            var picturesPath = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim).AbsolutePath;
            var filePath = Path.Combine(picturesPath, $"captured_qr_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.png");

            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
            mediaScanIntent.SetData(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(filePath)));
            Android.App.Application.Context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
            await DisplayAlert("done", $"saved to {filePath}", "ok");
#endif
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("error", $"this error: {ex.Message}", "ok");
    }
}`
   My goal is to take a picture of the code when it is detected to be sent to the server and displayed to check the code if it has a logo or not

Here is the screenshot

And here the qrcode for example  to capture it after scanner

